# Windows Terminal or Powershell alias function that accepts parameters

Tags: powershell

I want a simple alias I can run to

```
git add -A
git commit -m "$parm1"
git push
```

that's all. I'd take any help at this rate. Powershell is well horrible compared to Linux terminals but I'm trying to learn.

```
    function gitup {
    params(
    [string] $msg
    )

    git add -A
    git commit -m " $msg "
    git push
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo, it's "param" not "params".

As for having this as a convenient alias, it's recommended to put a function like this in your profile.

A question with more detail about profiles-
[How do I add a PowerShell cmdlet or function to my machine so that it is always available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344519/how-do-i-add-a-powershell-cmdlet-or-function-to-my-machine-so-that-it-is-always)